# Do I have problem with some hidden characters in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I use data from MS Excel further in MS Access where I try to create several Queries. My Table contains the following numbers:

```
Table:
"111_1"
"222_2"
"123_3"
```

So, if I've built those query, I always receive not correct results:
Query:

```
like "###_#"  | 0 Results
not like "###_#" | 3 Results
```

Why do I experience this kind of behavior? How can I avoid it? It seems like my inputs contains some hidden characters

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The *octothorpe* designates a *digit*, so try with:

```
"###?#"
```

or:

```
"###_#"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but your advice did not solve my problem. In my case, this problem only occurs in 20% cases. Some inputs work with the queries, but the rest of the inputs (20%) do not work. I've tried even "###*#" and nothing happened.

Comment: OK. Then you must double-check your data (which we don't have).

Comment: How can I double-check my data? I can provide my data, if it is possible ...

Comment: Visually. Compare those field values that look similar, where some are filtered and some are not. There must be some difference.

Comment: Thank you, I found the problem. The problem was hard to see, but the difference between underscore cause the problem. So, I replace all underscore, and now it works.